# Python import package from the wrong directory(outside of the virtualenv)

Tags: python, virtualenv

I was working on my virtualenv on a Ubuntu server. When I tried to import scipy. The module was somehow imported from outside of the virtualenv, and I don't want this behavior to happen.(That's what virtualenv is for, right?)

I checked what python I am using, and it's the one from my virtualenv

```
$ which python
/mydir/.venv3.6/bin/python
```

Then I checked if scipy is installed in the virtualenv

```
$ which pip
/mydir/.venv3.6/bin/pip
$ pip list
...
scipy    1.3.1 
...
```

However, when I import scipy, it's imported from outside of the virtualenv. Other modules work just fine.

```
$ python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul  3 2019, 15:36:16)
...
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
>>> print(numpy)
<module 'numpy' from '/mydir/.venv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>
>>> print(scipy)
<module 'scipy' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/scipy/__init__.py'>
```

I uninstall scipy and reinstall it, but nothing changes.
Why is this happening?

Comment: What's your PYTHONPATH environment variable set to?

Comment: From my setting.json: "python.pythonPath": ".venv3.6/bin/python"

Comment: @loguar2 `PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable listing path(s) to Python **libraries**, not the binary. And what is that `setting.json`? We don't use no `setting.json` with Python, is it a config for some other software? Also please bear in mind a virtualenv could be created with access to global libraries; how did you create the virtualenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what's causing this.
In the end, I created a Conda environment. And everything works just as expected from there.